# using numpy 'where' with an array subset

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm using python 2.7.13, and I'm perplexed by a behavior that I'm seeing when using array slicing with numpy.

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array([1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
print a
print a[1:]
print a[1:] > 3

print np.where( a[1:]  > 1 )
```

I was expecting that I would see for the final output [2 3 4 5 6 7 8] i.e. the indices of the array that were found within the slice.

My goal was to apply the Boolean mask to all elements of the array *except* the first element. Then to grab value in the array that corresponded to the first 'True' value in the index array. Is this possible?

Comment: `where` just tells you where `a[1:]>1` is `True`.  It does nothing with `a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this solves your problem:

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array([1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
b=a[1:]
print np.where( b  > 1 )
```

In your case, the `print` statement returns the element indices in the array `a`, while skipping the first elememnt.
to get the indices in array `a`, `print np.where(a>1)`
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is doing exactly what you want it to do. When you slice *a[1:]*, you get np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]). The output I got:

```
(array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], dtype=int64),)
```

is giving you the indices of 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, in the slice of *a* you specified.